# Improving Etags support for fortran?

Tags: ctags, xref, etags, fortran

When using `xref` with Fortran  I noticed that indexing by `etags` is highly incomplete; Almost exclusively subroutines (and maybe functions) are index, but modules, types, constants and global variables are all ignored.

This situation is even confirmed by the executable:

```
$ etags --help --lang=fortran
In Fortran code, functions, subroutines and block data are tags.
```

I am trying to fix the situation by adding regular expressions manually, e.g.

```
find -name "*.f90" | \
    xargs -d $'\n' etags --append \
          --regex='{fortran}/[[:blank:]]*module[[:blank:]]+\([[:alnum:]_]+\)/\1/i' \
          --regex='{fortran}/\(?:[^(]*\|.*::.*\)\(?1:\_<.*?\_>\)[[:blank:]]*=/\1/i' \
          --regex='{fortran}/[[:blank:]]*type[[:blank:]]*\(?:::\)?[[:blank:]]*\(?1:[[:alnum:]_]+\)/\1/i'
```

While it works, this makes me wonder if any better method is available -- maybe a specialized tools giving better etags for fortran, or at least a centralized place to store my custom regex list.

Comment: And you can also file a bug report asking for improvement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple solution: Use `ctags -e` instead of `etags` (assuming "Exuberant Ctags"<sup>[1]</sup>)

While `man ctags` explicitly says that `etags` is preferred for use with emacs, ctags seems to have much better fortran support. I now use:

```
ctags -e --recurse
#      :      :
#      :      `- Recursive processing of subdirectories.
#      :         Apparently also filters by extension, 
#      :         avoiding the need for manual filtering of `find`.
#      :
#      `- Output in emacs mode. 
#         Also changes filename from "tags" to "TAGS"
```

---

<sup>[1]</sup> There are multiple flavors of "Ctags". On my system, "Exuberant Ctags" was installed; Language support, Emacs-compatbility and supported flags may deviate. In the comments, "Universal CTags", a fork<sup>[[2]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ctags#Universal_Ctags)</sup> of "Exuberant CTags", was recommended.

<sup>[2]</sup> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ctags#Universal_Ctags

Comment: Is that Exuberant Ctags or “plain old” ctags?

Comment: @nega, exuberant ctags or universal ctags (recommended).